# How to substitute "U+...." with "\U000...." from a character in R?

Tags: r, gsub, substitution

I have this character:

```r
u<- "U+1F37A"
# output needed is "\U0001F37A"
```

So I used the gsub() function like this-

```r
v <- gsub("U\\+", "\\u000", u, fixed= F)
# however I am keep getting "U0001F37A" without "\" in front
# OR
# an error Error: nul character not allowed (line 1)
```

I have looked around Stack and there were couple of questions removing "\U000.." not inserting. Try to "reverse engineer" a bit, but I  failed.

I have also read this http://uc-r.github.io/regex but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use double escape

```
u1 <- sub("U\\+", "\\\\U000", u)
cat(u1, sep="\n")
#\U0001F37A
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! I got it :) No way to do this within same function?

Comment: @UltaPitt  You meant `gsub`  - `gsub` - global substitution.  Here, you are just substitutiing once, and for that `sub` is enough

Comment: yes buddy, I actually have a huge vector that needs this kind of substitution and I was thinking using gsub()-ing in some apply function. But this is good too.

Comment: Ok, if there are more than one instance to substitute in the same string then it needs `gsub`

Comment: Sorry to bother, it is like this `v <- c("U+1F37A", "U+1F37B", "U+1F37C")`, and I needed something that would get me `w <- c("\U0001F37A", "\U0001F37B", "\U0001F37C")` and so on. Also, when I captured the output using 'u1 <- capture.output(cat(u1, sep= "\n"))' I got `"\\U0001F37A"` as an output :(

Comment: @UltaPitt  There is only  single character.  It is just escaping the`nchar(sub("U\\+", "\\\\U000", v))#
[1] 10 10 10` and `nchar("U0001F37A")#
[1] 9`

Comment: Oh I see matey. Thank you so much for your help, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Akrun, I didn't do it. It was someone else, this actually accomplish what I needed to do.

Comment: @UltaPitt  I know that it is somebody else, but was curious about the reason